# Possible bug when querying using the 'take' method in Breeze

Tags: javascript, breeze

I am using breeze to query a table of customers. I have to implement a very complex query so I've decided to pass a parameter to the method and let the server to make the query. The problem is that using the method **TAKE** of **BREEZE** the list of customers that is returned by the server has a **different order** from the returned by the server.

I have made some test, and only this order is changed, when I am using the method TAKE of BREEZE. This is a bit of my code in the server and in the client:

```
//CLIENT
function(searchText,resultArrayObservable, inlineCountObservable){          

    query = new breeze.EntityQuery("CustomersTextSearch");
            .skip(0)
            .take(30)
            .inlineCount(true)
            .withParameters({ '': searchText});

    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data){
            //The data results are not in the same order as the server resturn.
            inlineCountObservable(data.inlineCount);
            resultArrayObservable(customerDto.mapToCustomerDtos(data.results));
    });
}


//SERVER ASP.NET WEB API
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> CustomersTextSearch(string textSearch = "")
{
    //Here, customers has the rigth order.
    var customers= _breezeMmUow.Customers.GetBySearchText(textSearch, CentreId);
    return customers;
}
```

Maybe is not a BUG, maybe I am doing something incorrect. Can somebody help me?

-------------EDIT-------------

1.3.2
Fix for Breeze/EF bug involving a single query with "expand", "orderBy", and "take" performing incorrect ordering.

I have found in the breeze page, that the problem was fixed, but I have the last version and it is still not working well with **TAKE**.

Comment: seems `.withParameters : { '': searchText};` invalid code

Comment: It was a mistake trying to write a simple example of my problem.

Comment: The problem is not that, the method in ther server is called, and it returns the rigth answer.

Comment: We were able to reproduce the problem and it appears to be a bug.
We are investigating further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug, and has been fixed in Breeze v 1.3.6, available now.